# Modeling Classes: hierarchy or attribute?

Tags: java, jpa, hierarchy, data-modeling

I have currently these 2 entities: 
Titular and Familiar (Family/kin/relative).

Familiar [0..*]<------>[1] Titular

These 2 classes has commons attributes of a person (firstName, lastName, birthDate....) and they are 2 kind of **Affiliate**

I want to unify those in one super class (generalization) **Person** but what I can't figure out is I should make Titular and Familiar extend Person or add Person as attribute of them.

Person also has to exists by itself (cannot be abstract) and not all Persons are Affiliates
BUT! I also need a way to establish/handle commons behaviors for Titular and Familiar.

Person [1]<------>[0..*] Titular

Person [1]<------>[0..*] Familiar

Titular [1]<------>[0..*] Familiar

So the doubt is:

```
public class Titular extend Person
public class Familiar extend Person {
```

or

```
public class Titular implement Affiliate {
    private Person person;

public class Familiar implement Affiliate {
    private Titular t;
    private Person person;
```

or (3rd thought)

```
public class Person {
public abstract class Affiliate {
    protected Person person;
public class Titular extends Affiliate {
```

Comment: If the objects stand for links between people then they should not extend `Person` - your second solution looks best.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon  I'll be great if you can take the time to share your thoughts on my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few test, I had decided for **Composition** over inheritance.
As one of tag is "JPA", this solution has to be mapped/annotated

..and none of the possible annotations suits

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED/SINGLE_TABLE/TABLE_PER_CLASS)
```

If Titular and Familiar extends from Person, the ORM required a "DTYPE" column in Person, which is useless for me because no matters in how many Titular or Familiar a Person can/will become in its life, it just must be ONE register of Person.

And being an Affiliate is a "concept" or behavior, which I need it to do some polymorphic tasks, it doesn't has any persistable attribute (FOR NOW!), I will make an Interface of it.

```
@Entity
public class Persona {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Integer id;


@Entity
public class Titular implements Afiliado {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Integer id;
   @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
   @ManyToOne(optional = false)
   private Persona persona;

@Entity
public class Familiar implements Afiliado {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Integer id;
   @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
   @ManyToOne(optional = false)
   private Persona persona;
   @ManyToOne
   private Titular titular;

public interface Afiliado {
   public String getNumero();
   //trick but necessary
   public Persona getPersona();

   //another default Java 8 implementations..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it, all Affiliates are persons too (or you have exceptions to this?)! So the right hierarchy is:

```
Person --- Affiliate --- Titular 
                      \- Familiar
```

Now, as to inheriting or having a pointer... that is called composition v/s inheritance and there are good arguments for both. The main reasons for chosing composition are

1. Mutable or optional relationships: Say, the owner of a car can change or a car can have no owner. A cat can not stop to be an animal and be something else.
2. Different Public API: While more work, composition allows you to manually forward whatever API you want to expose from your internal pointer, hiding or changing things from the "parent" as you will.

In general, you'll find inheritance makes more sense when ClassA IS-A ClassB, so you would not expect that to change nor would you want both classes to present a different API. You'll see this recommendation everywhere and it seems to fit your example like a glove.

Comment: Composition seems to be the solution, with the exception that a Titular/Familiar can't change of Person.

Person [1] ----- [0..*] Titular

Person [1] ----- [0..*] Familiar

Comment: That might be the case. It all depends on your domain. Would you have people un-affiliate? Can titulars become familiars or vice-versa? If so, then a specific instance does not follow the IS-A rule, but has a temporary relationship. The choice is your to make, since a problem's domain can be arbitrarily complex.

Answer (score 0):

Stated in verbose, we want the following behavior (If I understand you correctly):

`Titular` is a `Person` who supports the functionality of an `Affiliate`.

`Familiar` is a `Person` who supports the functionality of an `Affiliate` and is associated with a `Titular`.

After reading these two lines enough number of times, one possible solution that seems reasonable is:

```
public class Titular extends Person implements Affiliate {

public class Familiar extends Person implements Affiliate {
    private Titular t;
```